# Represent this ordered pair using a function

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, functions

> Suppose we have two boxes with Box 1 containing $p$ number of
> chocolates and Box 2 containing $q$ number of chocolates, $p$ and $q$
> being positive integers.
>
> A game consists of taking one chocolate from Box 1 at every odd turn
> and leaving Box 2 intact in that turn, and taking 1 chocolate from Box
> 2 at every even turn and leaving Box 1 intact in that turn.
>
> Represent this setup using an ordered pair of suitable functions.

I tried taking the ordered pair as $(f(n), g(n))$, where it goes like,

$$ (f(n), g(n)) \xrightarrow{\text{odd turn}} (f(n)-1, g(n)) \xrightarrow{\text{even turn}} (f(n)-1, g(n)-1) \xrightarrow{\text{odd turn}} \ldots$$

And then tried setting $f(n)$ as some combination of $(-1)^n$, but it didn't work. I don't know what else to do now.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$(-1)^n$ often a good idea when working with functions that act differently at odd and even inputs, but floor and ceil are the better choice in this case. $(p-\lceil n/2 \rceil, q-\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$ should be what you want

Comment: This isn't correct since the functions should be independent of p and q. Floor and ceiling also don't make sense because n is already an integer.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, meant to be $n/2$. I’m not sure I understand how the functions would be independent of p and q, do they represent something other than the amount of chocolates remaining after n turns?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

$$\big(f(n), g(n)\big) \xrightarrow{\text{$(n+1)$-th turn}} \left(f(n)-\frac {1-(-1)^{n+1}}2, g(n)-\frac {1+(-1)^{n+1}}2\right) $$
?

This assumes $\big(f(n), g(n)\big)$ represents the number of chocolates in Boxes $(1,2)$ after the $n$-th turn.